# Three different approaches to function encapsulation

Tags: javascript

I'm used to using a `class` to group common functions and data within a central contain. However, with javascript it seems there are multiple ways to do this, and in looking through code I see that often a non-class approach is even used quite frequency.

For example, if we take the following toy code to do some math (and allow method chaining), here are three variations I may sometimes see:

```js
// object approach
const MathObject = {
    num: undefined,
    setNum(x) {this.num = x; return this;},
    square(x) {this.num *= this.num; return this},
    print() {console.log(this.num); ; return this},
}
let m=Object.create(MathObject);
m.setNum(2).square().print()

// Response to the comment below -- can uncomment to test
// let diff_1 = Object.create(MathObject).setNum(2).square()
// let diff_2 = Object.create(MathObject).setNum(5).square()
// diff_1.print(), diff_2.print()
// let same_1 = MathObject.setNum(2).square()
// let same_2 = MathObject.setNum(5).square()
// same_1.print(), same_2.print()
```

```js
// function approach
function MathFunction() {
    let num;
    return {
        square(x) {this.num *= this.num; return this},
        setNum(x) {this.num = x; return this;},
        square(x) {this.num *= this.num; return this},
        print() {console.log(this.num); ; return this},
    }
}
let a = MathFunction()
a.setNum(2).square().print();
```

```js
// class approach
class MathClass {
    num;
    constructor(x) {this.num = x; /*ignored for now*/ }
    setNum(x) {this.num = x; return this}
    square(x) {this.num *= this.num; return this}
    print() {console.log(this.num);return this;}
}
m = new MathClass();
m.setNum(2).square().print()
```

Is this an accurate summary of the most common ways in javascript that data and methods are encapsulated? And is there ever a reason not to use a class (other than I suppose maintaining style on an older project)?

Comment: Not related to your actual question but in the first code example, `let m=Object.create(MathObject);` is unnecessary; you can directly call methods on the `MathObject` object literal. `Object.create` creates a new object and uses the passed argument as its prototype, which in your case is `MathObject`.

Comment: @Yousaf are you sure? Then I couldn't create encapsulate on multiple items -- see the updated first example.

Comment: If you need different _instances_ of the `MathObject`, then use the class approach or the [constructor function approach](https://jsbin.com/cazezupeda/1/edit?js,console,output) (Class approach itself is syntactic sugar for the constructor function approach). Defining methods on the `MathObject.prototype` object allows each instance to share those methods.

Comment: The first example `num` is an inherited property of the instances, whereas in the class example `num` is an own property of the instances. The function approach stores `num` in a closure, which is not shared by the objects created by the factory, every "instance" has its own copy of the variable. These differences are affecting to which approach you're using, it's more use-case-dependent than anything else.

Comment: Also note that `num` in "function" and "object" approach is not being used at all. `num` property is added on the object itself using `this.num`; so that `num` variable is also unnecessary in both approaches.

Comment: @Teemu could you clarify what you mean a bit by "The first example `num` is an inherited property of the instances, whereas in the class example `num` is an own property of the instances" ?

Comment: @Yousaf wouldn't `this.num` need to be used in the object approach though? For the function approach `num` would be ok, but for the object don't you need to refer to `this.num` to retrieve the value? -- for example: https://jsbin.com/bipesazugi/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Just log the instances, you'll find `num` in the first example from [[Proto]], and in the instance of the class it's an own property. In the object returned from the function, `num` is not a property at all, it's just a variable in a closure. When you'll set a value of a prototype property in a method, the prototype property is shadowed, and an own property is created to the instance. That's how `num` is used only with the class approach.

Comment: @David542 _"wouldn't this.num need to be used in the object approach though?"_ - you could use `MathObject.num` but in that case, all instances will refer to the _same_ `num` which is not what you want. Using `this.num` is the right approach but then you [don't need the num property on the object literal](https://jsbin.com/kudipuqafa/1/edit?js,console,output).